# Avoid double XML INSERT to SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to import XML data into SQL Server 2012. The import works correctly, but I would want to avoid double import. I already tried with `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but it didn't work.

The import:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tXMLImport(cText)
SELECT cast(CONVERT(XML,x.BulkColumn,2) AS varchar(max))
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\XML\Data.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

EXL file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tOrder>
    <cName>Name1</cName>
    <cID>100</cID>
</tOrder>
```

Now, it should be checked if **cID** value **100** from XML file already exist in

**dbo.tOrder** row **cOrderNumber**

```
    cOrderNumber
1   100
2   101
3   102
```

Following extention does not wokr:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM dbo.tOrder 
                WHERE x.value('(/tOrder/cID)') = dbo.tOrder.CorderNumber)
```

If yes, no Import to be done. Maybe some one can support me with?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really get this... If the same `cOrderNumber` exists already, wouldn't you try to update the existing row? Something like you'd do with `MERGE`?

But It might be something like this what you are looking for:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tOrder
                 WHERE x.exist(N'/tOrder[cID/text()=sql:column("cOrderNumber")])')=1)
```

(Untested air code)

This looks if there is any record within `tOrder` where the XML column `x` has any occurance of a node `<tOrder><CID>` with a value like the current cOrderNumber's value.

`T-SQL` adds the `sql:column()` method to `XQuery`, which allows to use the value of a row within the query. There's `sql:variable()` too.

The xml's method `.exist()` checks the XML for any existance of a given condition and returns with `0` or `1`.

### UPDATE

After reading your question once again, I'm not sure if I got this correctly... Please check the following. If this doesn't help, please use my code to set up a *stand-alone* sample to reprodcue your issue:

A dummy table with some orders

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(cOrderNumber INT, OrderName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
 (100,'Order 100')
,(200,'Order 200')
,(300,'Order 300')
```

--Try to insert an XML with the existing `OrderNumber=100`

```
DECLARE @xml100 XML=
'<tOrder>
    <cName>Name1</cName>
    <cID>100</cID>
</tOrder>';

INSERT INTO @YourTable(cOrderNumber,OrderName)
SELECT @xml100.value('(/tOrder/cID/text())[1]','int')
      ,@xml100.value('(/tOrder/cName/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @YourTable AS t2 
                 WHERE t2.cOrderNumber=@xml100.value('(/tOrder/cID/text())[1]','int'));
```

--Same code as above, but the order number is now a not existing number

```
DECLARE @xml101 XML=
'<tOrder>
    <cName>Name1</cName>
    <cID>101</cID>
</tOrder>';

INSERT INTO @YourTable(cOrderNumber,OrderName)
SELECT @xml101.value('(/tOrder/cID/text())[1]','int')
      ,@xml101.value('(/tOrder/cName/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @YourTable AS t2 
                 WHERE t2.cOrderNumber=@xml101.value('(/tOrder/cID/text())[1]','int'));
```

--check the result

```
SELECT *
FROM @YourTable;

nr  name
-------------
100 Order 100
200 Order 200
300 Order 300
101 Name1
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for support Shnugo.

I don't need to update **cOrderNumber**, because XML import with **ID 100* should be done only ones. It is only to avoid duplicates, when for example xml file going to be imported twice by mistake. Unfortunately, there is an error message: "A non-Boolean expression was specified in a context where a condition is expected." Actually it shouldn't be **WHERE NOT EXISTS** Maybe there is another way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Schiell, There was a typo, sorry for that! The `=1` checking the result of `.exist()` was part of the `XQuery`, but must be outside of course. This is quite probably the reason for the *non-boolean expression* error. But check my updated answer, there's an alternative approach too